# Requirements to do reverse Geocoding in Genexus Smart Devices

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I need to make a Reverse Geocoding for my SD app with Genexus X Ev3 U7, to show a location through aa given address in the map within the app. I've struggled for some time figuring out how to make it work with no luck.

I've already read all the documentation, followed the steps to get the API key from google (with Geocoding and Geolocation APIs enabled) and tried different ways with the methods shown in it and i haven't made it work.

Should I consider something else? Does anyone have done this before?

thanks before hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the main problem was that i was capturing the values of the Address Domain Collection variable all wrong.

All i had to do was to declare an &Address variable that read an &Addresses collection variable and to give it to a &Adrs VarChar variable:

```
For &Address in &Addresses    
    &Adrs = &Address    
    Load    
EndFor
```

where &Addresses = GeoLocationAPI.GetAddress(&GeoLocation)

I don't know how i didn't come up with this before.

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two methods in `Geolocation` external object: `GetAddress()` and `GetLocation()`.

If you are using it on the client-side, then both Android and iOS implementations use the platform's native implementation.

If the code runs on the server-side (C# or Java), then the implementation uses Google's geocoding services. The problem here is that there is no way to provide an API Key, so the number of allowed requests by day may be too low (depending on your usage).

Comment: I've already used the methods you mention on client-side reading Geolocation API's documentation, but what i can't figure out is it supposed to get the addresses from the "our" database or get it directly from Google's database? and secondly, is it a way to access to that information from Google?

Comment: Android and Web implementations use Google's services. iOS implementation uses Apple's. There is no way to get addresses from your database.